# Converting a type symbol to a java.lang.Class instance

Tags: clojure

Here is my problem:
Suppose I require `clojure.reflect :as r` and then, for example, do

```
(->> (r/reflect java.lang.String)
                :members
                (filter #(= (:name %) 'getBytes))
                first
                :return-type)
```

This will evaluate to `byte<>` which is a symbol. How can I map that symbol to a Java class, that is, how can I write a function `type-symbol-to-class` such that

```
(assert
  (= (class (byte-array [1 2 3]))
     (type-symbol-to-class 'byte<>)))
```

does not throw an exception? It is good if that function works for more symbols than just `byte<>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clojure reflection library does a lot of work ([1](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/reflect.clj), [2](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/reflect/java.clj), [3](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/asm/Type.java)) to prettify the output (including the argument / return type names) and it is not a straightforward task to do a reverse transform.

If you need a `Class` object, you can just use Java's reflection tools instead of `clojure.reflect`:

```
(= (->> java.lang.String
        .getDeclaredMethods
        (filter #(= (.getName %) "getBytes"))
        first
        .getReturnType)
   (class (byte-array [1 2 3]))) # -> true
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer! I didn't know about the Java reflection tools, but as you suggest, using them may be the preferred way to go.

Comment: If you want to use `clojure.reflect/reflect`, you can also try `AsmReflector`, which does not prettify the type names, instead of the default `JavaReflector`, but it seems to work only on Java 7 or earlier.